# in R detect previous value that is different and add new column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

the idea is to detect the previous mode and add it to a new column.

```
travel <- structure(list(time = structure(1:19, .Label = c("16:20:20", 
"16:20:21", "16:20:22", "16:20:23", "16:20:24", "16:20:25", "16:20:26", 
"16:20:27", "16:20:28", "16:20:29", "16:20:30", "16:20:31", "16:20:32", 
"16:20:33", "16:20:34", "16:20:35", "16:20:36", "16:20:37", "16:20:38"
), class = "factor"), mode = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("car", 
"bus stop", "walk"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

Here is how the data should look like:

```
    time        mode       previous_mode
1   16:20:20    walk   
2   16:20:21    walk
3   16:20:22    walk
4   16:20:23    bus stop   walk
5   16:20:24    bus stop   walk
6   16:20:25    bus stop   walk
7   16:20:26    bus stop   walk
8   16:20:27    bus stop   walk
9   16:20:28    walk     bus stop
10  16:20:29    walk     bus stop
11  16:20:30    walk     bus stop
12  16:20:31    walk     bus stop
13  16:20:32    walk     bus stop
14  16:20:33    walk     bus stop
15  16:20:34    car        walk
16  16:20:35    car        walk
17  16:20:36    car        walk
18  16:20:37    car        walk
19  16:20:38    car        walk
```

thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(travel)
# Create groups based on mode
travel[, groupid := rleid(mode)]
# Get last row of previous group
travel[, previous_mode := shift(travel[, last(mode), by = groupid]$V1)[.GRP], by = groupid]
#        time     mode groupid previous_mode
# 1: 16:20:20     walk       1          <NA>
# 2: 16:20:21     walk       1          <NA>
# 3: 16:20:22     walk       1          <NA>
# 4: 16:20:23 bus stop       2          walk
# 5: 16:20:24 bus stop       2          walk
# 6: 16:20:25 bus stop       2          walk
# 7: 16:20:26 bus stop       2          walk
# 8: 16:20:27 bus stop       2          walk
# 9: 16:20:28     walk       3      bus stop
#10: 16:20:29     walk       3      bus stop
#11: 16:20:30     walk       3      bus stop
#12: 16:20:31     walk       3      bus stop
#13: 16:20:32     walk       3      bus stop
#14: 16:20:33     walk       3      bus stop
#15: 16:20:34      car       4          walk
#16: 16:20:35      car       4          walk
#17: 16:20:36      car       4          walk
#18: 16:20:37      car       4          walk
#19: 16:20:38      car       4          walk
```

Comment: this function is really slow. I have to make this for over 300mio rows. Is there an other option?